# Change menu link in flash site

Tags: php, flash

I've got a flash site and php panel. It's xml file is dynamic. And i want add external link on a menu item.

E.G. News menu go to news.com

I found process.php in panel/application/controllers. With the following:

```
//News
        if($lang == 'tr')
        {
            $nTitle = 'Haberler';
            $nName = 'Haber Listesi';
        }
        else
        {
            $nTitle = 'News';
            $nName = 'News List';
        }


        echo '<page>
                    <title><![CDATA['.$nTitle.']]></title>
                    <data>news</data>
                '.$this->getpagebackground('news').'
                    <page>
                        <title><![CDATA['.$nName.']]></title>
                        <data>news_list</data>'.$nl;

        $newsRs = $this->db->query("Select date_format(date,'%d.%m.%Y') date,content,content_en,id,title,title_en From news Where status = 10 Order By viewOrder Desc");
        if($newsRs[0])
        {
            foreach($newsRs as $news):
                if($lang == 'tr')
                {
                    $nContent = $news->content;
                        $newsTitle = $news->title;
                }
                else
                {
                    $nContent = $news->content_en;
                        $newsTitle = $news->title_en;
                }
               echo   '<news>
                                <data>news_'.$news->id.'</data>
                                <title>'.$newsTitle.'</title>
                            <date><![CDATA['.$news->date.']]></date>
                                <sum>'.substr($nContent,0,150).'</sum>
                            <content><![CDATA[<p>'.$nContent.'</p>]]></content>'.$nl;
               $newsGallery = $this->db->query("Select * From news_media Where status=10 And news_id=".$news->id);
                   if($newsGallery[0])
                   {
                       echo '<gallery>'.$nl;
                       foreach($newsGallery as $ng):
                           echo '<item>'.$ng->media.'</item>';
                       endforeach;
                       echo '</gallery>'.$nl;
                   }


                   echo '</news>'.$nl;
            endforeach;
        }
        echo '</page>'.$nl;
```

Can i change link in here?

Comment: There are no links in this XML. Only news title, content etc. Also if news has gallery, also adds images.

Comment: @EPyLEpSY but i don't found true xml files.

Comment: Dynamic XML generated with this PHP script. There wont be a XML file.

Comment: @EPyLEpSY Well, how can i change menu link?

Comment: I think this Flash news site dont need "links". Creates news objects from XML. So, if you want to add link system, you have to do a lot of changes in Flash/PHP.

Comment: @EPyLEpSY How can i create objects from XML? E.G. import News code in manuel xml file and upload in data directory?

Comment: Look to what xml this php file creates. If this files are on a server, go to this php with your browser and copy/save export as xml file. But after that, you have too change Flash's xml path to your xml file.